# Custom Audio Recorder Framework Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift3, audio-recording

I am creating an audio recording framework, it gets compiled correctly. When I use this framework in a project, the recording file gets created in documents folder as specified in framework but it's size remains at 4KB and does not increase and no audio is there in the file. I have given 30 seconds duration for recording.I have used AVFoundation for audio recording and the same code works if i use it directly in my project but invoking the code through custom created framework doesn't work.

```
public func startRecording() {
    do {
        if (recordingSession != nil) {
            return
        }
        recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)

        recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    print("allowed")
                    let audioFilename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.caf")
                    print(audioFilename)
                    let settings = [
                        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatAppleIMA4),
                        AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
                        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
                        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 0
                    ]

                    do {
                        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
                        self.audioRecorder.delegate = self
                        self.audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
                        let audioHWAvailable = self.recordingSession.isInputAvailable
                        if !audioHWAvailable
                        {
                            print("no audio input available")
                            return
                        }
                        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

                        self.audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 30)
                        if self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
                        {
                            print("Recording started")
                            self.audioRecorder.record()
                        }

                    } catch {
                        self.finishRecording()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("failed to record!")
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("failed to record!")
    }

}
```

I have this startRecording method in framework class which I call from my project.

EDIT: When I add timer after self.audioRecorder.record() line, the recording works but I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by taking help from Apple Support team.

By making the call to startRecording() through a global variable of AudioRecording Class, it worked without adding timer.